# Random music player when win in the game

Tags: android, audio, random, soundmanager2

I make small game and there is music when you finish. Now I have one sound and would like to have 3 or 4 which play randomly, so you hear different music each time you finish. 
I have SoundManager.java where

```
public static final int SOUND_WINNER = 4;
public static final int SOUND_LOSER = 5;
public static final int SOUND_WINNER2 = 6;
public static final int SOUND_WINNER3 = 7;
```

and also

```
    public static void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
    mContext = theContext;
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0); 
    mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
    loopedSoundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);      

    addSound(SOUND_WINNER, R.raw.win);
    addSound(SOUND_LOSER, R.raw.lose);
    addSound(SOUND_WINNER2, R.raw.win2);
    addSound(SOUND_WINNER2, R.raw.win3);
```

In game activity I put

```
    private void win(){ 
    SoundManager.playLoopedSound(SoundManager.SOUND_WINNER);
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

I was trying to do something like this but with no success

```
private void win(){ 
    Random random=new Random();
    int r = random.nextInt(4);
    if(r==0){
    SoundManager.playLoopedSound(SoundManager.SOUND_WINNER);
    } 
    if(r==1){
    SoundManager.playLoopedSound(SoundManager.SOUND_WINNER2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works form me `playRaw(_this, R.raw.fail)`, it should also work for you.

```
private static void playRaw(Context _this, int resource) {
    PREFS = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_this);
    if (PREFS.getBoolean("SOUND_IN_GAME", true) == false) {
       return;
    }
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(_this, resource);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

The lines below let you make settings which allow you to turn off/on sounds. You can delete it.

```
PREFS = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_this);
if (PREFS.getBoolean(Global.soundInMatch, true) == false) {
     return;
}
```

In your case, you can also turn on looping flag

```
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```